# Trying php to reload page

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, refresh, reload

I am trying to use an image as a button to refresh pages on a website. The footer (a php include) is currently using this code to refresh each page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript: location.reload(true);" name="Reset page" title="Reset page"><img src="/images/refresh.png"></a>
```

which of course works. BUT I would like to improve it. Essentially, it would be something like this:

```
onClick="javascript: window.location.href='abcd.html';"
```

BUT I need it to work dynamically because I'm using php pages. So I was thinking this would work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript: window.location.href='<? php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>';" name="Reset page" title="Reset page"><img src="/images/refresh.png"></a>
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? I'm using `<? php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>` wrong (obviously), so, any ideas for assistance? Thank you for any help!

Comment: onClick="location.reload();" if you only want to refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem noticed is you have a space between `<?` and `php` in the following line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript: window.location.href='<? php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>';" name="Reset page" title="Reset page"><img src="/images/refresh.png"></a>
```

Also you want to echo out the value for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.  You are just calling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Also as @NickCoons pointed out when using the `echo` construct you need to add a semi-colon i.e. `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`.

Try the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript: window.location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';" name="Reset page" title="Reset page"><img src="/images/refresh.png"></a>
```

Comment: Also, the OP's example is missing the PHP semi-colon (it has the one for JS). Your example fixes this, but no mention of it. You may want to include that information explicitly in the answer.

Comment: @NickCoons, Thanks.  I've added a sentence for that as well.